# rotating vector3d around vector3d

Tags: vector, 3d

I apologize for asking this question as I know it has been asked and answered many times. I'm literally hours into learning 3d and the math involved.

I have two vector3ds. A is (0,0,0) and B is (0,0,-500). I want to rotate B around A by a set degree.

Can someone provide a neophyte answer? The solutions I've seen are areas I'm trying to learn but don't yet understand.

Comment: you can't rotate around anything without specifying a _center **point** of rotation_

Comment: The center point is vector A and I want vector B to rotate around A by a specific angle while maintaining it's distance from vector A. Sorry if that wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: That's still unclear - rotation requires two things - a _center point of rotation_, and an _axis of rotation_.  Your `A` although you've described it as a vector is in fact that _center point_, and the fact that it is the origin simplifies the math because you won't need a multi-step transform nor 4x4 homogenous coordinates.  However you do still need to supply an _axis of rotation_.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: (specifically the paragraph titled "Rotation matrix from axis and angle")

Comment: Well, I guess that confirms my nubie status… I want it to rotate around the Y-axis. I have no background in 3d math and the wiki page you provided and many others including ones here, provide matrix math I've never seen before and am trying to understand right now. Think of trying to explain to a monkey, then dumb it down a little...

Comment: If A was not the zero vector, then we could have taken that as the axis of rotation.  [Axis-angle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) is probably the form you want, especially the Rodrigues' rotation formula. To be pedantic rotations in 3D are always about a line, you can specify a line by a point and a direction along the line, however you can use any point on the line so the point is not really the center. You probably have some line which passes through the origin.

Comment: @Salixalba yes, that's a more technically accurate description.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you've clarified that you simply wish to rotate about the Y axis.   This is actually effectively just a 2D rotation, where the X and Z coordinates change, but the Y coordinate is unchanged.

Therefore:

```
x' =   x cos(theta) + z sin(theta)
z' =  -x sin(theta) + z cos(theta)
```

See [this SIGGRAPH link](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm#Y-Axis%20Rotation)

Comment: Thank you Alnitak, your perseverance is admirable. 45 years out of college and my math skills have atrophied drastically. Your answer above at least looked familiar to me, but I've botched something somewhere. `code` farpoint.X = farpoint.X * cos(heading) +  farpoint.Z * sin(heading)
farpoint.Z = -farpoint.X * sin(heading) +  farpoint.Z * sin(heading) `code` Am I translating you example right. Feeling pretty ignorant about now...

Comment: @BillMartini you must store the new X and Z coordinates in temporary variables, otherwise the new value of `farPoint.X` will be (incorrectly) used in the second calculation instead of its original value.  Also, don't forget that the computer's math functions will almost certainly use radians rather than degrees.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, probably should have caught that. My head is still spinning from those matrix formulas. Yeah, the line above multiplies heading by a constant converting into radians. I just started playing with openGL and I've been able to heavily modify a starter example in a short time, but I'm quickly discovering my math abilities are a show stopper. Thank you for your help.